# How to position a Row inside a Container so it doesn't overflow

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have a **Row** inside of **Expanded**. Inside that **Row** I want multiple Containers (so again I need a Row) and inside every **Container** I want to have multiple children, again I need a **Row** widget. All of that needs to be responsive. With the following code the widget overflows:

```dart
 Widget getCard(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Column(children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(flex: 1, child: _plateNumberWidget()),
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Text("2"),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                flex: 8,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [Text("Test1"), Text("Test2")],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("Test3"),
                          Text(
                            "Test44444444444444444444",
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ))
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [],
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
```

[image]

If i use Flexible, the overflow is fixed. But it doesn't position the widgets as i want (the green container should be right after the "Test2" text -> the grey container should take only the space it needs as in the first case.

```dart
Expanded(
                flex: 8,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [Text("Test1"), Text("Test2")],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Flexible(child: Text("Test3")),
                            Flexible(
                              child: Text(
                                "Test444444444444444444444444",
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ))
```

[image: It prevents the overflow]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Expanded(
        flex: 8,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: Row(
                children: [Text("Test1"), Text("Test2")],
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text("Test3"),
                    Flexible(
                      fit: FlexFit.tight,
                      child: Text(
                        "Test44444444444dsfasdfasd4444444444444",
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ))
```